# Save linq variable to add more where clauses

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to save a "linq-object" and then add where clauses. This will build but crashes at the first row with the error below. I can see there are two types in the anonymous part and I try to cast it to only one of them. But how do I do it correctly?

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2 [SubscriberContact,Subscriber]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SubscriberContact]

```
Dim subscriberContacts As IQueryable(Of SubscriberContact) =
            (From sc In GetTable(Of SubscriberContact)(), s In GetTable(Of Subscriber)()
             Where sc.Subscriber.SubscriberId = s.SubscriberId)


If Not searchCriteria.CustomerNo = Nothing Then
    subscriberContacts = From sc In subscriberContacts
                         Where sc.Subscriber.CustomerNumber.Value = searchCriteria.CustomerNo()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both types in the future projection, you can use type inferencing on the first query as follows, just make sure NOT to include ordering and assigning subscriberContacts to the ordered result as that will change the infered type. If you need ordering, use a new variable name.

```
Dim subscriberContacts =
            (From sc In GetTable(Of SubscriberContact)(), s In GetTable(Of Subscriber)()
             Where sc.Subscriber.SubscriberId = s.SubscriberId)


If Not searchCriteria.CustomerNo = Nothing Then
    subscriberContacts = From sc In subscriberContacts
                         Where sc.Subscriber.CustomerNumber.Value = searchCriteria.CustomerNo()
End If
```

Looking back at your original query, do you really need a join here? The sc.Subscriber object is the same as s in the object graph.